# sending a simple text file using NFC

Tags: android, nfc, data-transfer

I have an application which allows the user to create his business/personal cards.
I save those cards as JSON string in my database.
Now, I want the users be able to share these cards using NFC. 
what I want to do is, when the users select the card he wants to send, I write the string in the file named "xyz.Xcard" (so that my application in the receivers card would detect it) and then send it using NFC.
Can any one please suggest a simple code that would help me send a simple text file using NFC in Android.

And also I am facing difficulties in understanding the basic terms that are being used on the NET like, 
scanning the tag, eading the tag, Ndef message, ndef record etc etc.. 
thats why I am not able to understand the codes present here and there. 
can anyone in simple words explain me these things and also provide a hint to write this simple code??

this is somewhat i want to achieve
user 1:
(select the card to be sent-> fetch the JSON string from database ->write the string to file with ".Xcard" extension -> send it via NFC)
How will this happen? what are the things involved? NFC scanning? writing? reading?

will this send the file to all the users who are in range? (nfc enabled)

user2: 
(first he has to enable the nfc-> then the file is received)
is the receiving handled by default by Android?
what i mean to say is, when the file is received will it be shown in the default noftifications that the file has been received.
so that after clicking on that notification my app will start....

thankyou!!

Comment: From [leo9r](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2482894/leo9r): [How to NFC on the Android Platform](http://www.jessechen.net/blog/how-to-nfc-on-the-android-platform/)

Comment: From [Bassem Sarhan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5670191/bassem-sarhan): [Communication between Android using NFC to send text](http://android-er.blogspot.com.eg/2014/04/communication-between-android-using-nfc.html)